# Caindo no catch ao tentar estabelecer uma conexão

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Estou usando Netbeans e não consigo estabelecer uma conexão. Adicionei o .jar (postgresql-42.2.5.jar) do postgre na pasta lib e testei a conexão na aba do Netbeans (Service > database), ok deu certo. porém continuo caindo no bloco catch
Segue o código:

```
package teste.de.conexão;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConexaoJDBC {

    String caminho = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres";
    String user = "postgres";
    String password = "postgres";

    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException{      
        Connection con = null;
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(caminho, user, password);
        System.out.println("Conexão aberta com sucesso!! :)");
        return con;

    }
```

Classe co método main:

```
package teste.de.conexão;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class TesteDeConexão {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConexaoJDBC JDBC = new ConexaoJDBC();
        try {
            Connection conexao = JDBC.getConnection();
            if(conexao != null){
                System.out.println("Existe uma conexao");
                conexao.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex){
            System.out.println("Erro"); 
            ex.getMessage();
        }

    }
```

Saída:

```
    Erro
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Por qual motivo continuo caindo no catch? devo adicionar mais algo para que o Netbeans encontre o .jar do postgres?

Comment: Faz um favor? Onde está escrito `System.out.println("Erro");` modifique por  `System.out.println("Erro: " + ex.getMessage());` e mostre a mensagem de erro.

Comment: Era um problema com a senha de autenticação, notei também que não estava imprimindo o retorno do ex.getMessage(); por isso não era exibido na saída. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Bom Dia,

Adicione a linha na sua classe de conexão.

`Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");`

Deste modo ele consegue identificar qual driver deve ser utilizado para esta conexão.

Comment: O Class.forName(); não se fez necessário, consegui estabelecer a conexão sem essa linha

Comment: Legal!!! O que você fez pra resolver o problema?

Comment: Eu não estava imprimindo o getMessage() da exception, quando o fiz, me avisava do erro na senha do banco